# SQL Tree Traversal - Mesh nodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy

I have the following data in my database:

```
Parent      Child
======      =====
1           2
1           3
2           4
2           5
3           6
5           7
```

I want to retrieve all children and grandchildren of this tree. Can I use it with a WITH recursion?

The output should be:

```
Parent      Child
======      =====
1           2
1           3
1           4
1           5
1           7
2           4
2           5
2           7
3           6
5           7
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT parent, child, 1 AS depth
  FROM MyTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t1.parent, t2.child, depth+1
  FROM cte t1
  INNER JOIN @t t2 ON (t2.parent = t1.child)
  WHERE depth < 2
)
SELECT parent, child 
FROM cte
```

Comment: Almost there. I'm not sure why you used the WHERE clause.

Comment: You asked for children and grandchildren.  The `depth < 2` clause will exclude great-grandchildren and beyond